# property grid Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'x'

Tags: .net, properties, propertygrid

I am using property grid to show object properties. Dynamic properties must be shown according to conditions. I needed to show list items as a drop-down list.
so I write some classes which are necessary. (please consider this list is dynamic too).

I have a custom property grid  as you can see :

```
    public class myPropertyGrid : PropertyGrid
        {
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        public myPropertyGrid()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();          
        }

        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            if( disposing )
            {
                if(components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        #region Codice generato da Progettazione componenti
        /// <summary> 
        /// Metodo necessario per il supporto della finestra di progettazione. Non modificare 
        /// il contenuto del metodo con l'editor di codice.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            // 
            // UserControl1
            // 
            this.Name = "myPropertyGrid";           

        }
        #endregion      

        protected override PropertyTab CreatePropertyTab(Type tabType)
        {           
            myTab t = new myTab();
            return t;
        }           
    }   

    public class myTab : PropertyTab
    {
        public myTab()
        {            
        }

        // get the properties of the selected component
        public override System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(object component, System.Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties;
            if(attributes!=null)
                properties=TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(component,attributes);              
            else
                properties=TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(component);    

            //Componet must implement the ICUSTOMCLASS interface.
            ICustomClass bclass=(ICustomClass)component;    

            //The new array of properties, based on the PublicProperties properties of "model"
            PropertyDescriptor[] arrProp = new PropertyDescriptor[bclass.PublicProperties.Count];                                       

            for (int i=0;i<bclass.PublicProperties.Count;i++)
            {
                //Find the properties in the array of the propertis which neme is in the PubliCProperties
                PropertyDescriptor prop=properties.Find(bclass.PublicProperties[i].Name,true);
                //Build a new properties
                arrProp[i] = TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(prop.ComponentType, prop, new CategoryAttribute("جزئیات"));
            }
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(arrProp);
        }

        public override System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(object component)
        {                     
            return this.GetProperties(component,null);
        }

        // PropertyTab Name
        public override string TabName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Properties";
            }
        }

        //Image of the property tab (return a blank 16x16 Bitmap)
        public override System.Drawing.Bitmap Bitmap
        {
            get
            {               
                return new Bitmap(16,16);;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a class named **PropertyList** , This class is for adding properties to the property grid and removing properties from property grid.

```
    public class PropertyList : NameObjectCollectionBase
    {
        public void Add(Object value)
        {
            //The key for the object is taken from the object to insert
            this.BaseAdd(((CustomProperty)value).Name, value);
        }

        public void Remove(String key)
        {
            this.BaseRemove(key);
        }

        public void Remove(int index)
        {
            this.BaseRemoveAt(index);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            this.BaseClear();
        }

        public CustomProperty this[String key]
        {
            get
            {
                return (CustomProperty)(this.BaseGet(key));
            }
            set
            {
                this.BaseSet(key, value);
            }
        }

        public CustomProperty this[int indice]
        {
            get
            {
                return (CustomProperty)(this.BaseGet(indice));
            }
            set
            {
                this.BaseSet(indice, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

And a class for custom property

```
public class CustomProperty
    {
        private string sName = string.Empty;
        private bool bReadOnly = false;
        private bool bVisible = true;
        private object objValue = null;
        private object tag = null;
        private string displayName = string.Empty;
        public CustomProperty(object tag, string sName, object value, Type type, bool bReadOnly, bool bVisible)
        {
            this.tag = tag;
            this.sName = sName;
            this.objValue = value;
            this.type = type;
            this.bReadOnly = bReadOnly;
            this.bVisible = bVisible;
        }

        public CustomProperty(object tag, string displayName, string sName, object value, Type type, bool bReadOnly, bool bVisible)
            :this(tag,sName,value,type,bReadOnly,bVisible)
        {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }

        private Type type;

        public Type Type
        {
            get { return type; }
        }

        public bool ReadOnly
        {
            get
            {
                return bReadOnly;
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return sName;
            }
            set
            {
                sName = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Visible
        {
            get
            {
                return bVisible;
            }
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get
            {
                return objValue;
            }
            set
            {
                objValue = value;

            }
        }
        public object Tag
        {
            get
            {
                return tag;
            }
            set
            {
                tag = value;
            }
        }

        public string DisplayName
        {
            get
            {
                return displayName;
            }
            set
            {
                displayName = value;
            }
        }
}
```

I want to add combo box that is created from dynamic list , for this purpose I have write this code :

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(VersionConvertor))]
[Editor(typeof(VersionTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public class VersionClass
{
    public VersionClass()
    {

    }
}

public class VersionConvertor : TypeConverter
{

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
public class VersionTypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{

    private IWindowsFormsEditorService _editorService;
    private ListBox lb;
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        // drop down mode (we'll host a listbox in the drop down)
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        _editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

        // use a list box
        lb = new ListBox();
        lb.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
        lb.SelectedValueChanged += OnListBoxSelectedValueChanged;
        lb.DisplayMember = "Name";


        List<string> listItem = new List<string>();
        listItem.Add("a"); // assume that these items are added dynamically
        listItem.Add("b");
        foreach (string item in listItem)
        {
            lb.Items.Add(item);
        }

        lb.SelectedItem = listItem[0];
        lb.ValueMember = listItem[0];

        _editorService.DropDownControl(lb);
        if (lb.SelectedItem == null) // no selection, return the passed-in value as is
            return value;

        return lb.SelectedItem;
    }
    private void OnListBoxSelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lb.SelectedItem = ((ListBox)(sender)).SelectedItem;
        _editorService.CloseDropDown();
    }
}
```

When I click on alphabet drop down list and choose an Item , error comes :
[image]

[image]

How Can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but I have an answer.

The options in your ComboBox are strings; you are explicitly adding them to `lb.Items` in `VersionTypeEditor.EditValue()`. From the question I gather that the Alphabet property must be set to an instance of VersionClass. That's the source of your error: the form is expecting a VersionClass, and the ComboBox is passing it a string.

What you need is to convert the string to a VersionClass. You have already set up a VersionConverter class and applied it to VersionClass using the TypeConverterAttribute. Now you need to add the logic for the conversion by overriding the `TypeConverter.CanConvertFrom()` and `TypeConverter.ConvertFrom()` methods. Here's an example (untested):

```
public class VersionConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            // conversion logic goes here
            return convertedVersionClass;
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that answers your basic question. I also notice, however, that you're explicitly adding options using `lb.Items.Add()` in `VersionTypeEditor.EditValue()`. You can dynamically populate your ComboBox more easily by overriding more methods in VersionConverter. Specifically, you want to override `TypeConverter.ConvertTo()` to take a VersionClass and return a string representation that will appear in the ComboBox, and then override `TypeConverter.GetStandardValues()` to return a TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection containing the objects that you want to appear in the ComboBox.

A lot of what I've stated here, including `TypeConverter.ConvertTo()` and `TypeConverter.GetStandardValues()`, is discussed in more detail on [this MDSN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx).